# Publishing Actions: link back to website from user wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, publish

I am building a website that will require the user to provide permission for us to post a story back to the users wall when the user takes an action on my website. I would like the story to include a link back to my website so that friends can see the actions taken.

I am not sure of the correct permissions because I cannot get a link back to my website from the story post. I saw publish_stream, but that appears to be old now. Any pointers to FB policy and documentation would be appreciated. I

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making stream posts, you should instead use Open Graph actions, which will give you a much better result and feel less 'spammy' to your users. I can't post code that will do this for you as it would need to fit into your existing setup, however it is a relatively simple process, which is well documented (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/):

1. Auth users by prompting them to give `publish_actions` permission and any other permissions your app might need.
2. Store the users access token in your database (not necessary if you're using the client-side Javascript SDK, but you might want to do it anyway)
3. Setup your Open Graph Actions and Objects in the [Developer Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
4. When a user performs a relevant action in your app, make a simple Graph API call to the following endpoint:
   `https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE:YOUR_ACTION? YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE=YOUR_OBJECT_URL&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`
5. Done.

You can add extra elements to the action, such as [action links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/), however the basics are outlined above. Once you've performed those steps, the user will see something like this on their Timeline:

[image: https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/action_links_example_friendreact.png/]

The part that says 'on NYCCookbook' is customisable and clicking on most parts of this story will bring Facebook users back to your site. There are many benefits you can get [if you implement this all correctly](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/bestpractices/grow-app-open-graph/).

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I'll dig into the documentation.